# Почему не устанавливаются динамически отступы для ImageView?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть ImageView и нужно установить отступ снизу.

Делаю вот так

```
ivRedPoint = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rlRedPoint);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(25, 12, 32, 21);
ivRedPoint.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Вот XML

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rlRedPoint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/style_red_point"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Не реагирует этот `ImageView` ни на какие отступы...

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Поменяйте значение WRAP_CONTENT на MATCH_PARENT в LayoutParams, или попробуйте напрямую задать отступы вашему ImageView.

Comment: У вас LinearLayout без ориентации и в нём использовать android:gravity="center" тоже особого смысла нет. Сложно представить как вообще должна картинка сейчас отображаться

Comment: @Tommy Если задать MATCH то ImageView растягивается на весь экран. А что значит напрямую задать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Когда в LinearLayout один элемент он не чувствителен к ориентации... А android:gravity="center" как раз располагает картинку по середине этого LinearLayout...

Comment: в разметке в смысле

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, т.е. вам надо картинку отобразить по центру некоторого пространства, но при этом не сосем по центру? Думаю вам тут вообще не нужен обрамляющий контейнер

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, я попробовал создать чистый проект и просто в дефолтной разметке поставил `ImageView` и установил ей красную точку так вот динамические настройки я так понимаю доступны только для вью которое MATCH , но мне это не подходит так как если я устанавливаю MATCH для своего  `ImageView` то оно естественно растягивается на весь экран

Comment: А у тебя изображение сейчас вообще отображается? У ImageView сейчас стоит android:visibility="invisible"

Comment: @artemiygreg в разметке invisible , но в коде я при инициализации устанавливаю visable